# Magento 2.4.1 - "No such entity with customerid = "

Tags: payment, magento2.4.1, place-order

I have an error on Magento 2.4.1 during the checkout process.

Basically, I try to place an order as a guest, having Store > Checkout > Checkout Options > Allow Guest Checkout = Yes, but I get the following error on the last step, after I select the payment option and hit the payment button.

This is the error message "No such entity with customerId = ", being determined by "payment-information" endpoint.

`rest/romanian/V1/guest-carts/fY4IwgAe0uGhaEwOgJYUf9e9VaWebenz/payment-information`

Here's the trace:

`{"message":"No such entity with customerId = ","trace":"#0 \/home\/b2b\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\GuestPaymentInformationManagement->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder('fY4IwgAe0uGhaEw...', 'iulianpaulembac...', Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment\\Interceptor), NULL)\n#1 \/home\/b2b\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->___callParent('savePaymentInfo...', Array)\n#2 \/home\/b2b\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}('fY4IwgAe0uGhaEw...', 'iulianpaulembac...', Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment\\Interceptor), NULL)\n#3 \/home\/b2b\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Checkout\/Model\/GuestPaymentInformationManagement\/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('savePaymentInfo...', Array, Array)\n#4 [internal function]: Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder('fY4IwgAe0uGhaEw...', 'iulianpaulembac...', Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment\\Interceptor), NULL)\n#5 \/home\/b2b\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-webapi\/Controller\/Rest\/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#6 \/home\/b2b\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-webapi\/Controller\/Rest.php(188): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\Rest\\Request\\Proxy))\n#7 \/home\/b2b\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#8 \/home\/b2b\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#9 \/home\/b2b\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#10 \/home\/b2b\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Webapi\/Controller\/Rest\/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#11 \/home\/b2b\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(116): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#12 \/home\/b2b\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#13 \/home\/b2b\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch()\n#14 \/home\/b2b\/public_html\/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#15 {main}"}`

Here's what I did so far:

- disabled third-party plugins that were installed;
- changed the theme to Magento Luma 'cause I use a custom theme;
- tried to follow the trace and to fix the issue;

Is this a well-known bug?
How can I fix this or maybe figure out what's the issue?

Comment: It could be a corrupted quote, have you tried to flush your cookies?

Comment: Yes. I also tried using the incognito mode, different browsers, etc.
Also, I duplicated my database and removed all the quotes (and related data). Same error ...